# How to override wishlist price in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module

I am developing a custom module for price calculation and i was able to change the price in final_price.phtml to change prices and changed grid.phtml to override category page listing items.

it looks like the price has been updated to all the pages except wishlist.

how to make the price changes in wishlist too?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Hi @SunnyRahevar & sanjun can u please advise on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310131/magento2-display-configurable-product-price-range-on-wishlist-page

Answer (score 0):

you can override price.phtml from {Magento\Wishlist\view\frontend\templates\item\column\price.phtml}. It's block is "Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Cart" in wishlist_index_index.xml.